# Azure API Management and Microservice

Tags: azure-api-management

Can Azure API Management fulfill the below requirements or do I need to use Application Gateway as well along with Azure API Management?

- Route traffic to various microservices
- Cope with traffic demands and scaling
- Support API versioning

The microservices are hosted on Azure App services.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Whether API Management can do this, depends on what you exactly mean by these requirements.

- Route traffic to various microservices
  As you mention the microservices are Azure Web Apps, I assume you mean different microservices to route to, based on a different endpoint. 
  You can route a request based on the contents to a certain endpoint.
- Cope with traffic demands and scaling
  Azure Web Apps are scalable by default, and the traffic manager takes care of it. APIM can only handle traffic demands and scaling to the platform itself. You can scale up or out, even automated based on rules. However, as scaling might take some time it's recommended to monitor the capacity metric to accomodate for increasing load.
- Support API versioning
  APIM is 'just' an virtualization layer between the customer and the API. So having API versioning on APIM only makes sense when you actually do versioning on the API. In APIM you can create version sets which specify the versioning strategy for the API, based on header, path or querystring. An API can be deployed in APIM based on the version set, which makes it a versioned API.

Comment: We have multiple web app(ex- app1, app2, appN) and some of app has multiple microservices. if user hit https://app2.azurewebsites.net then user should go to main page and if they hit https://app2.azurewebsites.net/image then user should redirect to microservices having image. Is this possible by API Management Service?

Comment: Yes. Ultimately you can use policies in APIM to inspect your request and and route it dynamically to any URI you see fit. Or you can have it in a more static way, when APIM is configured to call contoso.com when request comes to /, and contoso.com/my when it comes to "/image", or any other way really.

Comment: Thanks, i am still not clear that if the url/path based routing can be done by APIM then what is the use of Application Gateway (if we don't want to use WAF)?

Comment: Application Gateway will only be used if you want to use APIM in 'internal' mode, exposing internal API's to the outside world. It seems your API's are in Azure so no need of it.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I didn't find any documentation on path based routing using APIM. Could you please share if you have any.

Comment: You have to work with policies. This is an example of routing based on body size (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/route-requests-based-on-size), but you can use any element from the request to route on.